# opening october cms in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I am unable to open October CMS in my localhost. I've `IIS` installed in my PC. When I type localhost in browser, `IIS` is opened.
For October CMS, I've installed `XAMPP`.

```
apache port -> 1234,1443
mySQL port -> 3306
```

phpmyadmin url is

```
http://localhost:1234/phpmyadmin/
```

while installing October CMS, it asked for

```
Application URL [http://localhost]:
> http://myoctober.dev
```

I kept the above application url.
Then I tried to open by url
http://localhost:1234/myoctober.dev and http://localhost:1234/myoctober

but it is showing

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.3
```

How to resolve this issue? Please help!!!

Comment: As Apache is listening on port 1234 then you have to add the port number to ALL urls that are served by Apache so `localhost:1234/......`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've edited my question. I tried it but can not open. Thank You!

Comment: WHere did you install October

Comment: @RiggsFolly You mean path to October folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\myoctober` or something else. Please clarify.

Comment: Well then try `localhost:1234/laravel` or maybe `localhost:1234/laravel/myoctober`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the installed path of October, your url should be `http://localhost:1234/laravel/myoctober/`. Try once.

Answer (score 0):

October CMS has some server requirements for web hosting:

1. PHP version 7.0 or higher
2. PDO PHP Extension
3. cURL PHP Extension
4. OpenSSL PHP Extension
5. Mbstring PHP Library
6. ZipArchive PHP LibraryGD
7. PHP Library

Some OS distributions may require you to manually install the PHP JSON and XML extensions. For example, when using Ubuntu this can be done via `apt-get install php7.0-json` and `apt-get install php7.0-xml` respectively.

When using the SQL Server database engine, you will need to install the group concatenation user-defined aggregate.

The wizard installation is a recommended way to install October. It is simpler than the command-line installation and doesn't require any special skills.

1. Prepare a directory on your server that is empty. It can be a sub-directory, domain root or a sub-domain.
2. Download the installer archive file.
3. Unpack the installer archive to the prepared directory.
4. Grant writing permissions on the installation directory and all its subdirectories and files.
5. Navigate to the install.php script in your web browser.

Follow the installation instructions...